# Envoy Downloading Speed Limit

Tags: throttling, rate-limiting, envoyproxy

Is there a way to limit download speed for end user in Envoy?

Ideally it should be dynamic (different download speed limit for different user).

There is some link https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v2/config/filter/fault/v2/fault.proto#config-filter-fault-v2-faultratelimit-fixedlimit but not sure how it's applicable for that task.